# ionic emulate not working connection error timed out

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator

ionic serve is working just fine

i tired all what i can find of emulate combinations:
ionic emulate (with or without android) (-c -l) or (-cls) is not working

I get popup alert
Application error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful(http://192.168.42.94:8100)
THEN
Application error: net:ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT(http://192.168.42.94:8100/)

I tried ionic address i get 3 addresses:

1) 192.168.1.102 (Wi-Fi 2) 
2) 192.168.0.100 (Ethernet)
3) localhost

1 and 2 does not work if I select 3rd option and then i run the emulate command, I get the address selection again with only the first two addresses without 3) localhost

I tried to restart the PC, closed everything.. it didn't help

My main html file is named:"index.html" and it's set correctly in config.xml

tried to uninstall the app from the emulator, but also didn't work.

note the android emulator has access to the internet, the other apps ex: browser are able to connect to the internet

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you could try to disable `Wi-Fi` or `Ethernet`, only  remain a specific ip so that emulator could access your local dev server successfully. Regards!

Comment: Unable to find an IPv4 address for run/emulate live reload.
Is WiFi disabled or LAN disconnected? (CLI v1.7.14)

Comment: Yes, and when you execute `ionic serve`, what the url in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8100/#/app/home

Comment: so, i tried genymotion with ionic run, and still the same error.. i will try create blank app and try

Comment: so an other app which i did in learning ionic worked just fine.. so it has to be something with the app i did... any suggestions?

Comment: Found it, actually just fixed it, i removed ./plugins and ./platforms and added android again with ionic platform add android then i run android and voila it worked.. but i found out that with -cls will not work.. so more digging, i tried ionic state reset.. and then it worked.. btw after the reset the crosswalk plugin was not installed.. maybe it's related.. i'm note sure